# Error in Simple Neural network Implementation using keras

Tags: classification, neural-networks, standardization, keras

I have a binary classification problem(benign/malicious) and I have applied simple neural network with one hidden layer for solving the problem. I have 46 features in my dataset and for the hidden layer I am using 46/2. Also my data is not scaled so for it I am using standardscaler. I am getting accuracy of around 99.79% with the code. However the accuracy was unexpected, I was expecting around 93-94%, I am afraid that I am leaking some data or making some silly mistake.

```
def create_baseline():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(23, input_dim=46, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_baseline, epochs=1000, batch_size=len(X), validation_split=0.15, verbose=0)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, cv=kfold)
print("%.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

I am using around 5871 malicious samples and 3488 benign samples.

Just to cross check I have implemented without cross validation, and I am getting ~99% accuracy in that also. Train test split is (70% - 30%)

```
scale = StandardScaler(with_mean=0, with_std=1)
new_X_train = scale.fit_transform(X_train)
new_X_test = scale.transform(X_test)


model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(23, input_dim=46, kernel_initializer="normal"))
model.add(PReLU(alpha_initializer='zero', weights=None))

model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(new_X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=len(X_train), validation_split=0.15)

scores = model.evaluate(new_X_test, y_test)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

print(history.history.keys())

plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

The plots I am getting are: [image: loss][image: accuracy]

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors, but just in case, try smaller batch size. I am not sure how keras handles when batch size is larger than the training set (which is your case, `batch_size=len(X_train)` but 15% of the training set are reserved for validation)

Comment: Now I am getting accuracy around 99.96% with batch_size = len(X_train)/4. Are there any implementation mistakes? Or this is because of the small datasize?

Comment: Your dataset size seems okay for such a small network. Are you sure there is no problem with your data, i.e. some of the features is very highly correlated with the output?

Comment: Can you suggest few methods to check that?

Comment: Well, computing the correlation between individual features and the output would be a good start.

Comment: @JanKukacka I have computed correlation between features and removed all features with correlation>=0.8, got 19 features, then with the output, I computed correlation and got 4 features with correlation>0.20 {-0.231764, -0.407881, 0.391524, 0.727126}, I think getting good correlation with output means the feature is good. How does this explain my problem?

Comment: of course input features should be correlated with the output. What @JanKukacka was probably suggesting is that if inputs are strongly correlated to the output, the problem is simple and thus it's easy to get a high accuracy. Another possible explanation may be that your problem is linearly separable. In this case, you don't even need neural networks: *regularized* logistic regression or a linear SVM will solve your problem just fine. The only way we can give you a definite answer is if you share your data. If there are privacy issues, just share standardized data `new_X_train` & `new_Y_train`

Comment: Also, I see you're not using any regularization at all. How did you split the train and test set? Just a usual random split? Getting basically the same accuracy on train and test set without any kind of regularization is quite impressive. There might be nothing wrong, anyway - I can easily get > 99% accuracy on MNIST with a simple CNN trained from scratch (NOTHING like GoogLeNet or ResNet). Sometimes, neural networks are just _good_ :-)

Comment: @DeltaIV I didn't see much difference in accuracy by using dropout even. Train test split is through train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42). Also I will try regularized logistic regression.

Comment: Ok, the splitting is correct, then, as I expected given the rest of your code. I put my money on "simple problem" - to check linear separability, regularized logistic regression could be a viable surrogate, but the best way is to fit a linear SVM and see if you get 100% accuracy. Without having access to anonymized data, I cannot give a better answer.

Comment: if the answer below answered your question, you can accept it by clicking on the grey tick below the answer's score. Otherwise, can you explain what you don't like about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine. Without access to your data, at least in standardized/anonymized form, it's impossible to give a definitive answer. However, when in this kind of predicament there is a standard set of checks worth going through<sup>1</sup>: some of these steps don't apply to you, but I'll include them anyway to make the list more comprehensive. As a best practice  these checks should be done *before* training the DNN, but they can be of help also when you have already used $k-$fold CV and/or training/validation/test set split to estimate correctly the generalization error, and you found a suspiciously low value.

1. check that all data transforms (or estimators, in Tensorflow lingo), are fit on the training set and applied to the test set, *for each fold* of $k-$fold CV. Using pipelines, as you did, is a simple way to make sure of this. Just check that all operations on data are performed inside the pipeline.
2. check that you're using the right metric for classification. In your case, accuracy makes sense because the two classes are reasonably balanced. But on a medical data set, where the incidence of the disease in the population is $0.1\%$, you will get $99.9\%$ accuracy on a representative data set, just by classifying each point to the majority class. In this case, $99.9\%$ accuracy is nothing to be surprised of, and actually accuracy is not the right metric to use here.
3. check that the problem is not overly simple. For example, it could be *linearly separable*. Some folks think this can be seen with PCA: PCA has nothing to do with linearly separable classification problems. Instead, use linear discriminant analysis or linear SVM: both will fit a linearly separable problem perfectly (or nearly perfectly), and get excellent out-of-sample performance. Alternatively, you can use *regularized* logistic regression (unregularized LR estimated with MLE is ill-posed for linearly separable problems). Plotting decision regions would also help a lot: `mlxtend`'s `plot_decision_regions` is a simple and convenient way to do this. Of course when you have more than 2 predictors you can only visualize 2D projections of the decision boundary, on the planes defined by the various pairs of input features.
4. create a correlation matrix including inputs and the class label: of course, computing the Pearson correlation coefficient between a continuous and a categorical variable doesn't make sense, but most good visualization tools (i.e., *not* `matplotlib`) will automatically switch to a visualization which makes sense. If there are a few inputs which are very correlated with the class label, then, even if there is significant correlation among inputs, a neural network is likely to do well. *Note*: after performing check 3, this check may seem redundant, but I believe visualization never hurts.
5. an heuristic I've found useful sometimes is to refit the NN on shuffled (permutated) labels. In this case the neural network has only one way to get good training set error: memorize the training set. This will usually manifest in much longer training time. Also, it has no way to get good test set error. If you still get excellent performance on the test set, then either there is something seriously wrong with your code (consider writing unit tests for each method you defined) or with the framework you're using. Consider opening a GitHub issue at this point.
6. Go to the extreme opposite: train on a single (or very few) data points. You should get $\sim 100\%$ accuracy on the training set (and extremely low on the test set). If you don't, again there's something seriously flawed with your code or framework.
7. Finally, try to obtain a few new test points, which you've never personally seen (let alone used in training) until now. The new test points must be representative of your real life usage of the NN. If you still get excellent accuracy, then get used to it, you're just very good at Deep Learning ;-)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> though I frankly would *love* to be in this kind of predicament more often, when my NN does greatly both under $k-$fold CV and on a well-designed validation set, without having to touch a single line of my architecture ;-)</sub>

Comment: ...not matplotlib but what?

Comment: @amoeba [DataExplorer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DataExplorer/vignettes/dataexplorer-intro.html),   [GGpairs](http://ggobi.github.io/ggally/#ggallyggpairs) or even `pairs`, with customized panel functions :-D

Comment: Wait, that's for R, I thought we are talking Python (since the question was in Python)...

Comment: @amoeba I know, I know, I was just messin' with you ;-) (I thought the smiley would make it clear). For Python, to the best of my knowledge, there is nothing which is completely automatic. But combining the excellent [seaborn.pairplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) (especially with the `hue` setting) with [factorplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html) or in general checking `seaborn` [capabilities for plotting of pairwise relationships]( http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html#plotting-pairwise-relationships-in-a-dataset) should 1/

Comment: 2/ help. At least, it's a vast improvement over all the manual tinkering you would have to do in `matplotlib`. Finally, for simpler cases than what I was talking about, `pandas` [plotting.scatter_matrix](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-matrix-plot) can help, but you miss the possibility to combine it with other `seaborn` bonanza.  By the way, any suggestions for learning Python, coming from R/matlab? Courses, books, etc.